# RaspberryPi Shell frozen after Python-Curses (Ctrl-C)

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, curses

I have a small Python application which gets me some output with simple curses.
I want this app to run as long as the user doesn't press a specific button.
In the past I just used Ctrl-C to quit my app. And actually, that's still working here too, but apparently I can't get any input into my terminal after quitting (except KeyboardInterrupt).

I tried catching the exception and resetting the curses-settings and some other things. I can't test-run the original app on my Mac, because its using GPIO Pins but the script beneath works on my Mac and after quitting with Ctrl-C everything is fine. On the Pi its causing the same behaviour though.

Thanks in Advance :-)

```
import time
import curses
import threading
import random
            
class SomeOutputtingThing:
    
    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        threading.Thread(target=self.show_values, daemon=True).start()
    
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        
    def show_values(self):
    
        stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        
        try:
            while self.running:
                stdscr.addstr(0,0, "Some valuable Data i want to see: {}".format(random.randint(0,5)))
                stdscr.addstr(1,0, "Some valuable Data i want to see: {}".format(random.randint(0,5)))
                stdscr.refresh()
        finally:
            curses.echo()
            curses.nocbreak()
            curses.endwin()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    foo = SomeOutputtingThing()
    foo.start()
    time.sleep(15)
    foo.stop()
```

Comment: python doesn't restore the terminal modes on abnormal exit.  You may be able to use `stty sane` (ending that with a control/J)

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks for your response, going to try tomorrow - im still confused why it’s no issue on a mac but on the pi

Comment: It's hard to make a proper search to give examples, but I don't see why it should work better on a mac...